# How to blank my OpenGL texture

Tags: opengl, opencl

I created an OpenGL (GL_TEXTURE_2D) texture, made an OpenCL image2d_t buffer out of it using clCreateFromGLTexture(), I run my OpenCL kernel to draw to the texture, using clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects and clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects before and after, and then I display the result in OpenGL by doing this (I'm trying to simply draw my framebuffer texture to the window with no scaling, is this even the right way to do it?):

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(1920.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(1920.0f, 1080.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(0.0f, 1080.0f);
    glEnd();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

It works great except there's one problem, I can't figure out how to fill the texture with zeroes in order to blank it, so I see old pixels where no new ones were written.

Apparently there's no way to blank an OpenCL image object from the host, so I'd have to do it in OpenGL (before calling clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects of course), so I tried this:

```
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

However this doesn't do anything. It does do something on screen when I comment out the GL_QUADS block above, it's like glClear doesn't do anything on the texture itself but rather the screen directly. It's confusing, I'm not very familiar with OpenGL, how do I blank my texture?

Comment: Well, yes, `glClear` clears the screen (or rather, the currently bound framebuffer object). It doesn't operate on textures.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo; Not with that attitude. Hint: Bind the texture to a framebuffer object, then clear this.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL glClear clears the currently bound framebuffer. To make this operate on a texture create a framebuffer object, attach the texture to it, bind the framebuffer object for drawing operations and clear it (which will then clear the texture).

Comment: I had trouble doing that, turns out doing `uint32_t z = 0; glClearTexImage(texture_id, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &z);` works too!